# Does git-rebase include squashed commit messages?

Tags: git, gitlab, commit, git-rebase

I had some commits that I used `git rebase -i origin/my_branch` on and squashed them down. When I pushed to my GitLab repository, I noticed at the top of the commit page was the message the interactive session allowed me to set, followed by the messages of all the squashed commits.

Does `git-rebase` store previous messages by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn’t “store” them. It combines the messages of the squashed commits, and offers that combination as the commit message for the one resulting commit. You just didn’t *notice* that when you edited the commit message during the interactive rebase, because what the editor gives you is a multiline message with many commented sections.

Expert tip: If you wanted to remove the commit messages of the squashed commits from the resulting commit message by default, use `fixup` instead of `squash`.

Comment: I see. Guess I will have to look closer next time I do that. I don't mind it, I actually think its pretty clean, showing the "new" message and its "history" but as a single commit.

Comment: Good example here: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/git-interactive-rebase-squash-amend-rewriting-history